# PHP import single class with a few css and javascript files

Tags: php, file, import

I'm having a few css and js files. So i want to have those in the single class to be imported to different php files.

```
class generalStyles {

function getGenStyles(){
    echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css'/>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css'/>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/general.css'/>

        <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.cookie.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='js/basket.js'></script>
        <link rel='shortcut icon' href='../favicon.ico' type='image/x-icon''>
        ";
}
}
```

it is OK when I do import class to the files that are on the same level from root, but when I'm trying to import this to other level - styles are not applied.

```
include("../../generalStyles.php");
    $styles = new generalStyles();
    $styles->getGenStyles();
```

How can I fix that? thanks!

Comment: I assume you have to make the path to the css and javascript files a parameter of your getGenStyles function or use absolute paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either use absolute paths like [Victor Häggqvist suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20721620/php-import-single-class-with-a-few-css-and-javascript-files/20721715#20721672) or if that is not suitable for you you can make the path a parameter of your function:

```
function getGenStyles($path){
    echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='" . $path . "bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css'/>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='" . $path . "bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css'/>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='" . $path . "css/general.css'/>
        ....
```

and then call it like this for example, depending on the location of the actual php file where you make the include.

```
$styles->getGenStyles('../');
```

Answer (score 0):

It is your css and JS imports that assumes that you are in one place.

To make it work every where you could specify the entire domain path to the files.

Example:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://example.com/css/general.css'/>
```